# Mapbox GL JS: Control max zoom with geolocation control?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS v0.32.1 and I have [a geolocation control](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/) on my map.

I would like to make it so that the maximum zoom when the user geolocates is 8, so that the map zooms to the user's approximate location, not street location.

According to [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeolocateControl.event:geolocate) there should be a `geolocate` event available, but this isn't working for me:

```
var geoLocate = map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl());
geoLocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
    console.log('geolocated');
    map.setZoom(8);
})
```

Geolocating (in Chrome at least) still zooms to the maximum zoom level available, and I don't see a console log message when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Map#addControl`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addcontrol) returns `Map`. The [`geolocate` event](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol.event:geolocate) is fired on [`GeolocateControl`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol). The following should work:

```
var geoLocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl();
map.addControl(geoLocate);
geoLocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
    console.log('geolocated');
    map.setZoom(8);
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. smooth zoom to your location

```
var geoLocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl();

map.addControl(geoLocate);

geoLocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
   map.flyTo({
    center:[e.coords.longitude, e.coords.latitude], 
    zoom:16 //set zoom 
  });
});
```